# Is it necessary to do all the story for every character?

Tags: destiny-2

I unlocked all of the map with my main character, and made the story all again for a second character, but I'm tired of this. Is it really necessary to do all the story again for a third time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with that character, if you are not completing the story, you wont get acces to some of the milestones which get you better gear at the end.

And without the milestones you are going to get stuck at around 265 to 270.

Also if you complete the story you are getting access to the exotic questlines.

If you want that character just for pvp, it is not really necessary to complete the story, if you want to have some progress, you should complete it.

Comment: Also the access to Nightfall and raid is locked behind the story.

Comment: It may be worth explicitly noting that you can skip the cutscenes which makes completion time a fair chunk shorter.

Comment: And in many of the story missions there are large groups of enemies that actually can be ignored if you can get passed them. On my 2nd+3rd character I got through the entire story by only killing what was necessary and it was significantly faster besides having to grind some public events to make up the lost exp.